Camera View doesn't match the user view
I'm trying to import a 3D terrain in Blender, the terrain was way to big for the camera so I've moved it and make it bigger in order to see the object.
However when I do Ctrl+Alt+Numpad 0, it doesn't match the user view at all, and it's the same thing for the image render.
Does someone have an idea?
Thanks for your help (the project is due for tomorrow :( and I'm blocked for a moment now)



Here are my clipping values
I'm wondering if it's because my volume is not displayed on the camera, maybe it's transparent or something like that?


Did you adapt the Clip Start and Clip End of the camera, according to your scene dimensions ?

Yes, I've put the Clip Start on 10m and the Clip End on 100000m.

I don't really know the dimension of the scene but as it's a 3D terrain of the Everest Mount that should be fine? When I'm moving the cliping values, the model is not displayed anymore on the user view

could you please share your file? Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload

here is the link of the file : 

Viewports and cameras have different settings for clipping planes. You should set it for the camera in the Properties Editor, Data tab as well:


thanks it works now !

Consider accepting the answer as the solution then.
